# Github pages with custom domain names

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I'm using the Github Pages to host a static website under [my username](http://abeaumet.github.io). I wanted to access it with through *beaumet.me*. I did it by created a **CNAME** file containing *beaumet.me*, this part works.

I also use the GH to host project specific website on the `gh-pages` branch. I would like to access it with the following URL: *projects.beaumet.me/project*, but I didn't succeed.

I tried two things (In both cases, I did a A record pointing to `204.232.175.78`):

- Leave the project without a **CNAME** file, I was able to access it through *beaumet.me/project*
- Create a **CNAME** file containing *projects.beaumet.me*, I was able to access it through *projects.beaumet.me*

I want a mix of them: access a project website through *projects.beaumet.me/project*

Does anyone know how to do it?

Edit: I would like to be able to host N projects under the *projects.beaumet.me* URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a CNAME for `projects.beaumet.me`, and move all of the files in `gh-pages` to a `/project/` subfolder.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if I have two projects in two different repos. It seems I can only link one domain name with one project.

Comment: @abeaumet: Correct on both counts.  You can put all of the pages in a single repo, or you can ask GitHub to add a new feature.